# удаление элементов из списка python

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть примерно такой список

```
my_list=[
[1, 'in'], [2, 'out'],
[3, 'in'],[4, 'in'], [4, 'in'],
[5, 'out'],[6, 'out']
]
```

Элементов обычно больше. В нем встречаются иногда подряд идущие элементы со значением `in` или `out`. Как сделать можно если подряд идет больше одного такого повторения оставить только 1 элемент. А второй удалить?

Разобрался как удалить все с `in`

```
el = 0
while el < len(my_list):
    if (my_list[el][1] =='in' and my_list[el+1][1] =='in'):
        del my_list[el+1]
    else:
        el += 1
print(my_list)
```

как удалить теперь и все out?

Comment: "_как удалить теперь и все out?_" - а если хотя бы чуть-чуть подумать?

Comment: Какой должен быть результат? Только `[4, 'in']` надо удалить или все после `[3, 'in']` с `in`?

Comment: @dIm0n [
[1, 'in'], [2, 'out'],
[3, 'in'],[5, 'out']
] такой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для списков ненулевой длины:

```
import itertools

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

my_list=[
[1, 'in'], [2, 'out'],
[3, 'in'],[4, 'in'], [4, 'in'],
[5, 'out'],[6, 'out']
]

print([my_list[0]] + [y for x, y in pairwise(my_list) if y[1] != x[1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Просто "копируете" часть имеющегося у вас кода:

```py
my_list = [
    [1, 'in'], [2, 'out'],
    [3, 'in'],[4, 'in'], [4, 'in'],
    [5, 'out'],[6, 'out']
]

el = 0
while el < len(my_list) - 1: # Чтобы el+1 не выходил за границы массива
    if (my_list[el][1] =='in' and my_list[el+1][1] =='in'):
        del my_list[el+1]
    elif (my_list[el][1] =='out' and my_list[el+1][1] =='out'): # Копия
        del my_list[el+1]
    else:
        el += 1

print(my_list)
```